# Typecasting a boolean operation to a boolean results in false

Tags: php

In PHP, when typecasting a boolean operation which returns `true`, for some reason the interpreter will typecast it into a `false`. Why is this? Take the following example:

```
(bool)  1 === 1  // false
(bool) (1 === 1) // true
```

This operation should return `true`, but for some reason it returns `false`. When adding extra parentheses it does work correctly. Could someone explain why this is? I'm currently using PHP 7.0.8

Comment: Well with your two lines of code you already see how PHP works. `((bool)  1) === 1` <- after that you have `TRUE === 1` and those are not the same type anymore, so as result you get false as output.

Comment: I can tell only it's not about PHP version - `5.3` behaves the same way as `7.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order of operations. The first statement evaluates bool before the equality check

```
(bool)  1 === 1 is the same as ((bool)  1) === 1
```

Whereas

```
(bool) (1 === 1)
```

evaluates inside of the parenthesis first.

1 isn't the same thing as `TRUE`.